# How to convert dataframe to xml using xml2 package?

Tags: r, xml, xml2

I'm trying to update an xml file with new nodes using xml2. It's easy if I just write everything manually as text,

```
oldXML <- read_xml("<Root><Trial><Number>3.14159 </Number><Adjective>Fast </Adjective></Trial></Root>")
```

but I'm developing an application that will run calculations and then put those values into the xml, so I need a mix of character and variables. It ends up looking like:

```
var1 <- 4.567
var2 <- "Slow"
newLine <- read_xml(paste0("<Trial><Number>",var1," </Number><Adjective>",var2," </Adjective></Trial>"))
xml_add_child(oldXML,newLine)
```

I suspect there's a much less kludgy way to do this than using paste0, but I can't get anything else to work. I'd like to be able to just instruct it to update the xml by reference to the dataframe, such that it can create new trials:

```
<Trial>
  <Number>df$number[1]</Number>
  <Adjective>df$adjective[1]</Adjective>
</Trial>
<Trial>
  <Number>df$number[2]</Number>
  <Adjective>df$adjective[2]</Adjective>
</Trial>
```

Is there any way to create new Trial nodes in approximately that fashion, or at least more naturally than using paste0 to insert variables? Is this something the XML package does better than xml2?

Comment: Try `rio::export(dat, "dat.xml")` and see if it gives you an XML file you're happy with.

Comment: Error: object ‘read_xls’ is not exported by 'namespace:readxl'

Comment: @RichardMNIxon That error was solved for me by uninstalling and reinstalling `readxl` and then loading it prior to loading `rio`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have your new values in a data.frame like this:

```
vars <- data.frame(Number = c(4.567, 3.211),
                   Adjective = c("Slow", "Slow"),
                   stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

you can convert it to a list of `xml_document`'s as follows:

```
vars_xml <- lapply(purrr::transpose(vars),
                   function(x) {
                       as_xml_document(list(Trial = lapply(x, as.list)))
                   })
```

Then you can add the new nodes to the original xml:

```
for(trial in vars_xml) xml_add_child(oldXML, trial)
```

I don't know that this is better than your `paste` approach. Either way, you can wrap it in a function so you only have to write the ugly code once.

Comment: Thanks, I have way more than just two values per node, so this should at least be cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that builds on @Ista's excellent answer.  Basically, I've dropped the first `lapply` in favor of `purrr::map` (we could probably replace the second `lapply` with  a `map`, but I couldn't find a more readable way to accomplish that).

```
library(purrr)

vars_xml <- transpose(vars) %>% 
   map(~as_xml_document(list(Trial = lapply(.x, as.list))))
```